# Rails/Dragonfly: how to update magic colums like image_width

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dragonfly-gem

I use dragonfly to handle image attachments in my rails app.
I use the magic columns image_width and image_height in my model.
This worked nicely. Now I have gotten some images with a `image_uid` in the model, image is accessible, but `image_width` and `image_height` are not set. (It happened with the simple_dragonfly_preview plugin) 
Now how can I force to recalculate the values? So something like this in the model:

```
before_save :update_image_fields

def update_image_fields
  logger.info "Image size update"
  if image_uid.present?
    self.image_width = image.width # what to call here?
    self.image_height = image.height
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate dimensions of your image using ImageMagic analyzers http://markevans.github.io/dragonfly/imagemagick/#analysers.

Given you already configured ImageMagick plugin, the code to recalculate your image's height and width looks like this:

```
Photo.where(image_width:nil).each do |photo|
  photo.image_width = photo.image.analyse(:width)
  photo.image_height = photo.image.analyse(:height)
  photo.save
end
```

Comment: it looks like the `image.width` call just uses the magic column, I keep getting empty dimensions.

Comment: According to https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly/blob/master/lib/dragonfly/image_magick/analysers/image_properties.rb#L9 it should invoke Imagemagick's `identify` command to get width and height

Comment: When I debug, it calls "ensure_uses_cached_magic_attributes", which of course finds that I have magic attributs defined.

Comment: @Meier see my updated answer. You should use `photo.image.analyse(:width)`